# ie9 is clearing the developer console after the page finishes loading

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

If I have the developer console open while a page loads, I can see all my console.log statements logging. but as soon as the page is finished loading (with or without any errors), the console is cleared automatically and I can't get back to see any of the messages. how do I stop this unwanted behaviour? I want to see my log messages and objects.

Comment: is there a console.clear() somewhere in your code

Comment: Nope - first thing I checked for. Vanilla ie9, no extensions, default settings, win7. Happens on other pages too, I have discovered.

Comment: can you give me your url, I can check

Comment: no, I can't. for *what* will you check?

Answer (score 0):

The console could be clearing on mistake because it's received an (inaccurate) notification that the page has been navigated. You can turn off that behavior from the F12 menu:

```
Tools -> Clear Entries on Navigate -> Console (untick)
```

Does that workaround the issue?